# How to track or monitor xmlhttp requests (Ajax calls) with Selenium Web driver PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium

I need to find how many ajax calls are pending in current document with  Selenium Web driver PhantomJs, I don't have reference to ajax call objects

I tried by executing this javascript:

```
var s_ajaxListener = new Object();
s_ajaxListener.tempSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

function increaseCounter () {
    window.ajaxRequestCount = window.ajaxRequestCount + 1;
}
function decreaseCounter() {
    window.ajaxRequestCount = window.ajaxRequestCount - 1;
}
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    increaseCounter()
    s_ajaxListener.tempSend.apply(this, arguments);
    this.addEventListener("progress", increaseCounter, false);
    this.addEventListener("load",decreaseCounter , false);
    this.addEventListener("error", decreaseCounter, false);
    this.addEventListener("abort", decreaseCounter, false); 
}
```

But, while doing this `print "ax-count: ", browserInstance.execute_script("return window.ajaxRequestCount")` output is: `None`